# Counting Digits in a String - output not being correctly printed

Tags: java

My problem is to count digits in a given string,
here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s=" 1 3 4 5 22 3 2";
    int[] counts=count(s);
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        if(counts[i]==1) {
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " appears " + counts[i] +" time");
        }
        else if(counts[i]!=1 && counts[i]!=0) {
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " appears " + counts[i] +" times");
        }
    }
    }

public static int[] count(String s) {
int count[] =  new int[99];

for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
    ***count[i]++;***
}
}
    return count;
}
```

the desired output is that if x appears more than once then it should say *x appears n times*, but my output is something like this [Undesired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs78V.png)

The part I've bolded out is where I localised the problem, I cannot find a way to access that if 2 appears more than once, then count[2] must also gain a +1 value, I've tried using a conversion from String to Int but nothing seemed to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to copy/paste the undesired output into your question, rather than linking to an image of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why didn't you make array of size 10 and keep data in it. Something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s=" 1 3 4 5 22 3 2";
    int[] counts=count(s);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
        if(counts[i]==1) {
            System.out.println(i + " appears " + counts[i] +" time");
        }
        else if(counts[i]!=1 && counts[i]!=0) {
            System.out.println(i + " appears " + counts[i] +" times");
        }
}

public static int[] count(String s) {
    int count[] =  new int[10];

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) 
        if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
            count[(int)s.charAt(i) - (int)'0']++;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, I just want to ask the logic behind the (int)s.charAt(i) - (int)'0', how does it work? Pardon me I'm a newbie to Java Programming

Comment: charAt() gives the character at the index which is being cast to an int. I believe casting '0' to an int is 48. So if the chart at index 0 is 9, then the actual calculation would be 57 - 48. Look an an ASCII chart and it will make a bit more sense. The increment after the bracket is a bit weird to me though.

Comment: Without incrementation this line wouldn't do anything (just writing name of variable won't do anything). And aim of this loop is to count digits, so when I find one, I have to increment appropriate counter.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct check to see if the character is a digit, what you aren't doing correctly is incrementing the correct index. You want to convert the character to a number and use that number as your index. Try this

```
public static int[] count(String s) {
    int count[] =  new int[10];

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            count[Character.getNumericValue(i)]++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```